# Remover primeiro caractere pelo Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde.

tenho um varchar com alguns números

```
set @ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER = '01234567'
```

Gostaria de remover o zero somente se ele for o primeiro número da minha variavel, exemplo:

'0123456789' removendo o zero ficaria '123456789'

'123401234' não posso remover o zero ele não é o primeiro.

Tenho o comando

```
PATINDEX('%0%', @ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER);
```

mas ele sempre retorna o index, independente se ele é o primeiro ou não.

Comment: Uma opção é converter para int e depois de volta para varchar. Até quantos algarismos pode ter o número?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar o `PATINDEX` para isso: `%[^0]%'`

E para remover o primeiro caracter, você pode utilizar o [SUBSTRING()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187748.aspx), desta forma:

```
DECLARE @ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER varchar(60)
SET @ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER = '01234567';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER, patindex('%[^0]%',@ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER), 10)
```